# How to add kafka-connect-jdbc-5.5.0.jar to Debezium/connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium, confluent-platform

i had downloaded the kafka-connect-jdbc-5.5.0.jar file from confluent into my local machine.i would like to know a way to add this jar to plugin.path=/kafka/connect. i am trying to sink the data to mysql server so iam using "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector" but i am facing the "error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, i am using docker toolbox in windows machine

Comment: Why not just use `cp-kafka-connect` docker image that already has that JAR? Or why not use `confluent-hub` to install what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this examle [Dockerfile](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-smt/debezium-jdbc-es/Dockerfile). It demonstrates how to deploy sink connector for JDBC and Elasticsearch.
Generally the most important to remeber is that if `plagin.path` is set to `/kafka/connect` then the connector but be dpeloyed in a directory named `/kafka/connect/<arbitrary_name_dirname>`.